# RViz not loading configuration or display area

Tags: rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using ros indigo on ubuntu 14.04. When I launch RViz, I get no errors, but I get a screen like this, regardless of my configuration file
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ljarin/alexa-pandabot/master/Screenshot%20from%202017-04-21%2016%3A14%3A54.png

I get a grey box instead of the normal viewing window. I can add panels, but the display/visualization window does not seem to work at all. If I try to open a configuration, it just goes back to this screen.

RViz has always worked on my computer until today. I was installing openCV from source recently, which required some massaging of packages, which I assume is causing this problem somehow. I already tried `sudo apt-get install --reinstall ros-indigo-rviz`

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/259915/rviz-not-loading-configuration-or-display-area/) by [ljarin](https://answers.ros.org/users/29286/ljarin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2017-04-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I suggest you check this issue: [issue #1047](https://github.com/ros-visualization/rviz/issues/1047)

Cheers,
Marco.

---

Originally posted by [Femer](https://answers.ros.org/users/26134/femer/) with karma: 253 on 2017-04-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ljarin](https://answers.ros.org/users/29286/ljarin/) on 2017-04-21**:
Thanks for the quick response; that is the same issue. Although not a lot of great solutions :/

**Comment by [Femer](https://answers.ros.org/users/26134/femer/) on 2017-04-21**:
Have you tried to install rviz from source?

**Comment by [ljarin](https://answers.ros.org/users/29286/ljarin/) on 2017-04-22**:
I ran out of time, but I will try on Monday.

**Comment by [ljarin](https://answers.ros.org/users/29286/ljarin/) on 2017-04-24**:
compiling from source worked